# How to prove, for example, that $\frac{d}{dt} \langle \mathbf{L} \rangle = \langle \vec{\tau} \rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator

So I'm struggling to understand why $[V, L_x] = i\hbar[r \times \nabla V]_x$ to further prove that $\dfrac{d}{dt} \langle\mathbf{L}\rangle = \langle \vec{\tau} \rangle$, with $\vec{\tau}$  being the torque $\vec{\tau} = \mathbf{r} \times (-\nabla V)$, and $V = V(\mathbf{r})$ being the potential.

So, first of, the crooss product of the position with the potential's gradient is

$\mathbf{r} \times \nabla V = \begin{pmatrix} \hat{\imath} & \hat{\jmath} & \hat{k} \\ x & y & z \\ \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial z} \end{pmatrix}$.

Solving for one coordinate first, saying x, and using that $L_x = yp_z - zp_y$, I ended up at

$[V, L_x] = y[V, p_z] - z[V, p_y]$, and

$y[V, p_z] - z[V, p_y]= yVp_z - yp_zV - zVp_y + zp_yV = -i\hbar yV \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} + i\hbar y\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial z} + i\hbar z V \dfrac{\partial }{\partial y} - i\hbar z \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial y} = i\hbar\underbrace{\left(y\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial z} - z\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial y} \right)}_{= [\mathbf{r} \times \nabla V]_x} - i\hbar V\left(y\dfrac{\partial }{\partial z} - z\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \right) ,$

which is clearly different from $[V, L_x] = i\hbar [\mathbf{r} \times \nabla V]_x$ by the term $-i\hbar V \left(y\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} - z\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)$.

I can see I've obtained the x-component of the cross product betweet the position $\mathbf{r}$ and the gradient of the potential, but somehow the surving term had to be zero for I to obtain the correct result and I can't understand how will I make it disappear. Furthermore, the sign is switched up, as I should get a minus at the cross product rather than a plus. I would pretty much appretiate if someone could enlighten me on this one.

Answer (score 3):

So the question is basically about the commutator $$[V,p_x] = [V(x), {-i}\hbar\partial_x],$$
where you have been expanding this incorrectly as,
$$[V,p_x] \ne -i\hbar V(x) \partial_x + i\hbar \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}.$$ To understand why this is wrong, observe that you can substitute $V(x) = x$ and get the canonical communication relation $[x,p_x]=i\hbar$. So the one term is not meant to be there.

The usual advice we give to newcomers is to operate on a “test function,” and you will find the term which cancels your anomalous derivative.

Answer (score 2):

You have evaluated the commutator incorrectly. To avoid this,
whenever you evaluate a commutator, let it operate on some arbitrary function e.g., $f$ first. So first evaluate, $[V, L_x]f$ and after a little algebra, you will get $$\tag1 [V, L_x]=i\hbar L_x V$$ Since $$\tag2 i\hbar[r\times\nabla V]_x=i\hbar[y\partial_z -z\partial_y ]V$$ equations (1) and (2) are identical. That is, $$[V, L_x]=i\hbar[r\times\nabla V]_x$$